# jpg image not displaying in safari (iphone 3gs and ipod)

Tags: html, iphone, safari, jpeg, ipod

I have this image : 
   "http://interstatic01.gameloft.com/igp/videos/images/d9/end_screen_71.jpg"
 In this very simple html, it doesn't display for the 2 devices mentioned in the title.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div ><!-- it may show full image depending on browsers, eg: firefox  -->
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/nXxT5.jpg"   />
    </div>              
</body>
</html>
```

Note: if i enter the url directly in the url bar of the safari browser, i can see it.
It just happens when it is in a  tag or when set as css background

Comment: what does it say if you add alt="img" ?

Comment: nothing happens. I just see a very small square in the upper left portion of the page. After adding alt="img", that very small square just got 2 pixels wider i think

Comment: @Roadirsh The `alt` attribute is used to [provide a text that describes the image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute), for example for blind people or as a tooltip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is simply [too large for these devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) (see the *Know iOS Resource Limits* section). You need to serve a smaller image for these devices (how this is done is a different question to which I don't know the answer).

William Malone has a [Maximum Image Size Calculator](http://www.williammalone.com/articles/html5-javascript-ios-maximum-image-size/) that allows you to enter an image size and it tells you which devices are capable of displaying an image of that size.