# Images not opening on Safari & apple devices

Tags: php, css, image, ipad, safari

I am working on a website, the problem is some of the photos of website are not opening on some apple devices (iPad, iPad pro etc) and on safari browser. Example can be seen [here](http://www.dreamyflat.com/property?city=PARIS) (open in safari or apple device).

Even when I copy the image url and try to open it in a new tab, it doesn't opens, it just displays:

[image: Not showing image, showing ? instead]

I tried almost every solution I found on stackoverflow to the related problems, but no luck!

Any idea why is it happening?

**EDIT:**

It is not duplicate question because in my case pics have nothing to do with size, many pics having much larger size are being displayed properly.

Comment: What have your tried?

Comment: Images are too large: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073629/jpg-image-not-displaying-in-safari-iphone-3gs-and-ipod

Comment: @NilayVishwakarma Several image compressions, size specifications, removing anchor tags etc.

Comment: @Manu is not a matter of size, it's a matter of file format. They're not jpeg. Furthermore they're not large in bytes size and/of pixel size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Downloading and inspecting the images that doesn't show up, example...

```
$ file /Users/paolo/Desktop/14864236730ce9011e-original.jpg 
/Users/paolo/Desktop/14864236730ce9011e-original.jpg: RIFF (little-endian) data
```

...it turns out they are not `jpeg` as the extension suggest but `riff`

see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Interchange_File_Format

The `riff` format is a wrapper and in this case it wraps a `WEBP` image.

This is why Chrome is able to open the file and show the image.

You can identify the `RIFF` images with the `file` command line tool.

One tool you may use to convert them is [xnconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnconvert/)  (free and multi-platform)

I just tried it with the image above and worked fine.

You can use it to batch process multiple images too.

I have no idea how these imagese ended up there in that format. Probably there is some server-side script that converts uploaded images to WEBP/RIFF. But's just a guess of course.

Comment: Hmm..that's weird, I never uploaded any riff file (I didn't even know what's that), but is there any way to detect which images are riff (except downloading and inspecting each image, there are thousands of them) ?

Comment: I downloaded one of the pic which was not being displayed through its image url, I was not able to open it on my laptop (got error: It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.), I then converted it to proper jpeg format, was then able to open that pic on my laptop, then uploaded it back to its original location to check - but again neither it opened on safari nor on my laptop when I downloaded that pic again from image url..... its both funny & bizzare because there is no script on server that could have been converting that image to riff again. Any idea?

Comment: If you upload a JPEG then you get a WEBP on the website then there is a conversion happening at some point between the upload and the image being served to the client. That's the only thing we know for sure. - I can't give you more help than this. Isolate the point where images change format. Ex. on the web server storage they're still JPEG or already turned into WEBP?...

Comment: That should not be the case because: 1) I uploaded the image directly through ftp and not through website user panel so that any script can run, and 2) Why then only few images are not being displayed, if all are being converted then no image should be displayed.
Though I will check again thoroughly to be sure there is no script affecting the pics, at least now I know the reason of pics not being displayed, thank you:)

Comment: I know it is not the case of the OP, but just in case someone else (most likely future me) comes across this question with a similar problem: in my case, the culprit was the webp optimizer from image-webpack-loader.